# why spring-boot does not access the front-end packaged "dist" static resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, npm, deployment, vuejs3

When I import the files which the front-end developer packages the `dist` project, and `SpringBootApplication` run, I can visit `index.html`, but I can't read its static resources, can't show the pic, it's all black. And `index.html` source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./pwa-192x192.png">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="./safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#00aba9">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00aba9">
  <script>
    (function () {
      const prefersDark = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
      const setting = localStorage.getItem('vueuse-color-scheme') || 'auto'
      if (setting === 'dark' || (prefersDark && setting !== 'light'))
        document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark', true)
    })()
  </script>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./static/js/index-d3549438.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/index-db70e0a5.css">
</head>
<body class="font-sans">
  <div id="app"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

the positions of `dist` file : `resources/dist`, and my `dist` file contains `static` file.

And my configuration about SpringApplication is in `application.yml`:

```yaml
Spring:
 web:
  resources:
   static-locations: "classpath:/dist"
```

And I also add SpringWebMvcConfig.java in my config-files:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/dist/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/dist/");
    }
}
```

If possible, I would really appreciate it if you could help me point out the problem.
:)

I can visit "index.html" only use `npm`.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set it up the way you want it, but this is how I do it in my project. I copy the files to the `resources` folder of the java application. Here an excerpt of my `vue.config.js`:

```
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
    outputDir: 'src/main/resources/public/clientlibs/vue-dist'
});
```

Then you can access these from the spring templates with: `/clientlibs/vue-dist/vue-app.js`

Comment: oh thanks, I already figured out my problem. Similar to what you said, I probably put my `dist` in a wrong place, I should place in `resources/static`, not a `resources/dist` .